# Determing the file type during a DragOver event : UWP Media learning project

Tags: c#, events, drag-and-drop, uwp

I am trying to write a practice Drag and Drop program.

This program will display a picture (JPG or PNG or Bitmap) when one is dropped on it. It will play a music file when dropped on it and it will play a video when a video file is dropped on it. 
I would like the drop Icon to indicate what kind of file is about to be dropped when the `DragOver` event is fired. And if the file type is not compatible with my program I want the Icon to be able to indicate that as well.
I have been going through the `DragEventArgs` class for weeks trying to figure out a way of being able to tell the difference between the 3 types of media file but I have come up empty. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DragUIOverride` to customize the look of the dragged object.

You can set it with the `DragOver` event on the target element:

```
private async void Grid_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)  
{
    e.DragUIOverride.Caption = "Some caption";
    e.DragUIOverride.IsCaptionVisible = true;
    e.DragUIOverride.IsContentVisible = true;
    e.DragUIOverride.IsGlyphVisible = true;
    e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
    //check the type of the file
    var items = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();
    if (items.Any())
    {
       var storageFile = items[0] as StorageFile;
       if ( storageFile.FileType == ".jpg" )
       {
          e.DragUIOverride.SetContentFromBitmapImage(
             new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/jpgIcon.png")));
       }
       else if ( storageFile.FileType == "png" )
       {
          e.DragUIOverride.SetContentFromBitmapImage(
             new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/pngIcon.png")));
       }
       //...
       else
       {
          //for disallowed file types
          e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.None;
          e.DragUIOverride.SetContentFromBitmapImage(
             new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/errorIcon.png")));
       }
    }
}
```